# how to change input box value in html when selectbox is selected without changing the select box value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, select

i am trying to integrate payu payment gateway in my website so when a user selects the product info in my form, the amount should change accordingly, I have done the following:

```js
function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementById("myText").value = e.target.value
}
```

```html
<select name="productinfo" onchange="myFunction(event)" class="form-control">
  <option value="<?php echo (empty($posted['productinfo'])) ? '' : $posted['productinfo']; ?>" disabled selected>Choose Database Type</option>
  <option value="26,999">X 1.5</option>
  <option value="28,999">X 2.5</option>
  <option value="32,999">X 3.5</option>
  <option value="35,999">X 4.5</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="amount" id="myText" class="form-control"   value="<?php echo (empty($posted['amount'])) ? '' : $posted['amount']; ?>" readonly>
```

here the amount is being changed according to product select and am able to pass it to pay, what I want is the product info also to be passed like value="X2" in the form, is there any way to do it,please help, thanks in advance

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do. Can you give us more details?

Comment: @testing_22 i want different values for both, like example for selectbox I need value="X1" and amount value="26999",

Comment: Why dont you just change the select name to be **amount** and the input id="myText" change the name to **productinfo** . Then in your myFunction instead of assigning the value, assign the text. That should fix your problem

Comment: @slashroot i didnt understand, i want both the values as separate,

Answer (score 1):

Here try this:

```js
function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementById("myText").value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-price');
}
```

```html
<select name="productinfo" onchange="myFunction(this)" class="form-control">
  <option value="<?php echo (empty($posted['productinfo'])) ? '' : $posted['productinfo']; ?>" disabled selected>Choose Database Type</option>
  <option value="X 1.5" data-price="26,999">X 1.5</option>
  <option value="X 2.5" data-price="28,999">X 2.5</option>
  <option value="X 3.5" data-price="32,999">X 3.5</option>
  <option value="X 4.5" data-price="35,999">X 4.5</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="amount" id="myText" class="form-control"   value="<?php echo (empty($posted['amount'])) ? '' : $posted['amount']; ?>" readonly>
```

Comment: bro i get an error , no rpduct info passed

Comment: @BOOKTHEPARTY Did you update your SELECT option values? If you select option X 2.5 and post the form you should get **X 2.5** from $_POST['productinfo'] and **28,999** from $_POST['amount']